# How to avoid the duplicate count

Tags: crystal-reports

Using Crystal Report 7

```
ID Total

001 100
001 100
002 200
002 200
003 300
003 300
```

Formula for supressing the duplicate value

```
if {table1.ID} = previous({table1.ID}) then true else false
```

The above formula is working, but i want to sum of total value, when i use sum({table1.total}) = 1200, It should show 600 instead of 1200

Expected Output

ID Total

```
001 100
002 200
003 300
-------
    600
```

How to get a exact total.

Need Crystal report formula help or suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really address the underlying issue. Why are the rows being duplicated? I suspect there are additional columns you haven't shown us.

Alternatively you can:

- Group by ID, then use a running total set to evaluate on change of group
- Use a running total set to evaluate using the opposite condition to your suppression formula `{table1.ID} <> previous({table1.ID})`

P.S. You can write `if {table1.ID} = previous({table1.ID}) then true else false` as `{table1.ID} = previous({table1.ID})`